# formatting DATE-TIME IN COBOL

Tags: function, datetime, cobol

i want to format the FUNCTION DATE-TIME. What i have is

```
MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA
DISPLAY WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA
```

and I tried using a filler

```
01 WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA.                               
05 WS-CURRENT-DATE.                                 
   10  WS-CURRENT-YEAR         PIC 9(04).           
   10  FILLER                  PIC X(01)  VALUE "-".
   10  WS-CURRENT-MONTH        PIC 9(02).           
   10  WS-CURRENT-DAY          PIC 9(02).           
05 WS-CURRENT-TIME.                                 
   10  WS-CURRENT-HOURS        PIC 9(02).           
   10  WS-CURRENT-MINUTE       PIC 9(02).           
   10  WS-CURRENT-SECOND       PIC 9(02).           
   10  WS-CURRENT-MILLISECONDS PIC 9(02).
```

what I get is a result with the hyphen at the back like

```
2017122818242863-
```

but what I want is possibly this

```
2017-12-28-18:24:28:63
```

Pls help. Thanks in advance

Comment: So what have you tried ??? - Hint set up a current date to receive the `Function current-date` and a separate receiving field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you are seeing this hyphen at then end is because this is actual data definition `FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE` is expecting:

```
05 WS-CURRENT-DATE-TIME.            
   10 WS-CURRENT-DATE.              
      15 WS-CURRENT-YEAR  PIC  9(4).
      15 WS-CURRENT-MONTH PIC  9(2).
      15 WS-CURRENT-DAY   PIC  9(2).
   10 WS-CURRENT-TIME.              
      15 WS-CURRENT-HOUR  PIC  9(2).
      15 WS-CURRENT-MIN   PIC  9(2).
      15 WS-CURRENT-SEC   PIC  9(2).
      15 WS-CURRENT-MS    PIC  9(2).
   10 WS-DIFF-GMT         PIC S9(4).
```

You will notice that I have an extra field at the end for Greenwich Mean Time Difference. Also, you cannot just add filler to your definition and expect that function to know what to do with it. Basically what is happening is the hyphen that you are putting in (in the picture clause) is being overwritten by the data passed from the function what you need is 2 places in working storage. One to hold the return from the function and one to hold the formatted value, so something like this:

```
01 WS-TEMP-DT.   
   05 WS-TEMP-DATE-TIME.            
      10 WS-TEMP-DATE.              
         15 WS-TEMP-YEAR  PIC  9(4). 
         15 WS-TEMP-MONTH PIC  9(2).
         15 WS-TEMP-DAY   PIC  9(2).
      10 WS-TEMP-TIME.              
         15 WS-TEMP-HOUR  PIC  9(2).
         15 WS-TEMP-MIN   PIC  9(2).
         15 WS-TEMP-SEC   PIC  9(2).
         15 WS-TEMP-MS    PIC  9(2).
      10 WS-DIFF-GMT         PIC S9(4).

01 WS-FORMATTED-DT.   
   05 WS-FORMATTED-DATE-TIME.                       
      15 WS-FORMATTED-YEAR  PIC  9(4). 
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE '-'.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-MONTH PIC  9(2).
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE '-'.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-DAY   PIC  9(2).  
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE '-'.           
      15 WS-FORMATTED-HOUR  PIC  9(2).
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE ':'.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-MIN   PIC  9(2).
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE ':'.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-SEC   PIC  9(2).
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE ':'.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-MS    PIC  9(2).

MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO WS-TEMP-DATE-TIME
MOVE WS-TEMP-YEAR  TO WS-FORMATTED-YEAR
MOVE WS-TEMP-MONTH TO WS-FORMATTED-MONTH
MOVE WS-TEMP-DAY   TO WS-FORMATTED-DAY
MOVE WS-TEMP-HOUR  TO WS-FORMATTED-HOUR
MOVE WS-TEMP-MIN   TO WS-FORMATTED-MIN
MOVE WS-TEMP-SEC   TO WS-FORMATTED-SEC
MOVE WS-TEMP-MS    TO WS-FORMATTED-MS

DISPLAY WS-FORMATTED-DATE-TIME
```

Comment: WS-DIFF-GMT  PIC S9(4) describes a 4 position field. While PIC +9(4) would be better, the "sign" position may contain a "0".

Answer (score 3):

As Joe already said - if you move something to a group item you get the data in without conversion, so either move sub-fields or (if your compiler supports it - you've missed to specify which one you've used) use [`FUNCTION FORMATTED-DATETIME`](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/faq/index.html#function-formatted-datetime).

Answer (score 2):

CURRENT-DATE is a 21 character field with date, time, and offset from GMT. The "hyphen at the back" is actually the first position of the offset from GMT.

The UNSTRING statement may be used to move the individual parts of CURRENT-DATE.

```
       UNSTRING FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE
       INTO WS-CURRENT-YEAR WS-CURRENT-MONTH WS-CURRENT-DAY
           WS-CURRENT-HOURS WS-CURRENT-MINUTE
           WS-CURRENT-SECOND WS-CURRENT-MILLISECONDS
       END-UNSTRING
       DISPLAY WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to defined subfields under WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA to break out yy, mm, dd, hh, mn, ss, ms and then move those individually into the fields under WS-CURRENT-DATE and WS-CURRENT-TIME to properly get your '-' and ':' chars to show up.

Answer (score 0):

SaggingRufus's answer was informative. I've tried to produce the expected output using Reference Modification.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 WS-DATETIME              PIC X(21).
01 WS-FORMATTED-DT.
   05 WS-FORMATTED-DTE-TME.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-YEAR  PIC  9(4). 
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE '-'.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-MONTH PIC  9(2).
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE '-'.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-DY    PIC  9(2).
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE '-'.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-HOUR  PIC  9(2).
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE ':'.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-MINS  PIC  9(2).
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE ':'.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-SEC   PIC  9(2).
      15 FILLER             PIC X VALUE ':'.
      15 WS-FORMATTED-MS    PIC  9(2).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO WS-DATETIME. 
MOVE WS-DATETIME(1:4)  TO WS-FORMATTED-YEAR.
MOVE WS-DATETIME(5:2)  TO WS-FORMATTED-MONTH.
MOVE WS-DATETIME(7:2)  TO WS-FORMATTED-DY.
MOVE WS-DATETIME(9:2)  TO WS-FORMATTED-HOUR.
MOVE WS-DATETIME(11:2) TO WS-FORMATTED-MINS.
MOVE WS-DATETIME(13:2) TO WS-FORMATTED-SEC.
MOVE WS-DATETIME(15:2) TO WS-FORMATTED-MS.
DISPLAY WS-DATETIME.
DISPLAY WS-FORMATTED-DT.
STOP RUN.
```

Result:

```
2018011005202041+0000
2018-01-10-05:20:20:41
```