# STRING INTO multiple variables

Tags: cobol

Is there a way to use the `STRING INTO` with multiple variables?

For example (this works):

```
MOVE string TO variable1
               variable2
               variable3
```

The same example with `STRING INTO` (this doesn't work):

```
STRING string DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO variable1
                                     variable2
                                     variable3
```

Is there a way to put `STRING INTO` multiple variables? I need to move into alot of strings, so I don't like to write `STRING INTO` for every variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNSTRING` without the `DELIMITED` phrase, as in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48087123/9170346) for formatting date/time. The length of the recieving field determines the number of characters moved.